# @Published variables do not carry over as @Binding variables from Model to View to DetailView

Tags: swiftui, mvvm, core-location

I am trying to pass `shotCoord`, `ballCoord`, and `waiting` from `LocationManagerModel` to `ContentView`, and then to the `DetailView` of items on a list. I need these three variables to maintain their values when returning to the `ContentView` and selecting another item from the list. `Waiting` is used to control the state of the `DetailView` and works perfectly. `ballCoord` and `shotCoord` do not persist when returning to the `ContentView` and are reset to `nil`.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation


class LocationManagerModel : NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    enum LocationMode {
        case ball, shot, putt 
        //addNewShot(distance: Double, shotClub: Club)
    }
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    //@ObservedObject var club: Club
    @Published var shotCoord : CLLocation?
    @Published var ballCoord : CLLocation?
    @Published var waiting = false
    @Published var errorMessage = ""
    @Published var showError = false
    @Published var distance: Double?
    //@Published var shotClub: Club
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var mode : LocationMode = .ball
    
    public override init() {
        super.init()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
    }
    
    public func currentLocation(mode: LocationMode) {
        self.mode = mode
        locationManager.requestLocation()
    }
}

extension LocationManagerModel : CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
        showError = true
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        switch mode {
        case .ball:
            ballCoord = locations.last!
            //distance = ballCoord?.distance(from: shotCoord)
            
            print("shot:\(shotCoord?.coordinate as Any)")
            print("ball:\(ballCoord?.coordinate as Any)")
            //print(distance!)
            //addNewShot(distance: distance!, shotClub: Club)
            
        case .shot:
            shotCoord = locations.last!
            print("shot: \(shotCoord?.coordinate as Any)")
            
        case .putt:
            ballCoord = locations.last!
            waiting = false
        }
    }
    
    func addNewShot(distance: Double, shotClub: Club) -> Void {
        let club = shotClub
        let distanceYards = lround(distance * 1.09361)
        //let avgYards = club.yardsNum * club.strokes
        //club.strokes += 1
        club.strokesList.append(distanceYards)
        club.strokes = club.strokesList.count
        let sumArray = club.strokesList.reduce(0,+)
        club.yardsNum = sumArray / club.strokes
        
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }
    
    
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
        switch manager.authorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedAlways:
            return
            //print("authorizedAlways")
        case .authorizedWhenInUse:
            return
            //print("authorizedWhenInUse")
        case .denied, .restricted: print("denied")
            // show the error to the user
        case .notDetermined: print("notDetermined")
            locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        @unknown default: print("This should never appear")
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ClubDetailView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var club: Club
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @StateObject private var locationManager = LocationManagerModel()
    @State var newShot: Int = 0
    @Binding var waiting: Bool
    @Binding var shotCoord: CLLocation?
    @Binding var ballCoord: CLLocation?
    @Binding var shotClub: Club
    var body: some View{
        //let waiting = locationManager.waiting
        //let shotList = self.club.strokesList
        List {
            if self.club.putter == false {
                Section {
                    Text(self.club.name)
                    Text("Average distance: \(club.yardsNum) yards")
                    Text("\(club.strokes) Strokes Counted")
                }
                
                //ForEach(shotList) {shots in club.strokesList}
            } else {Text("This app is not designed to track putting data at this time.")}
        }
        
        
        if waiting == false && club.putter == false {
            Button(action: {locationManager.currentLocation(mode: .shot)
                waiting = true
                shotClub = club
            },label: {
                Text("Swing Location")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded, weight: .bold))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        
        if waiting == true && club.putter == false{
            Button(action: {locationManager.currentLocation(mode: .ball)
                //ballCoord = getBallLocation()
                //let distanceMeters =
                //                let distanceYards = lround(distanceMeters * 1.09361)
                //addNewShot(newShot: Int(distanceYards), shotClub: shotClub)
                
                print("shot: \(shotCoord?.coordinate as Any)")
                print(shotClub.name)
                shotClub = club
                //print(locationManager.shotCoord!)
                if shotClub.putter == true {
                    waiting = false
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Ball Location")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded, weight: .bold))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        if waiting == true && club.putter == true{
            Button(action: {
                //ballCoord = getBallLocation()
                //let distanceMeters = ballCoord.distance(from: shotCoord)
                //let distanceYards = lround(distanceMeters * 1.09361)
                //addNewShot(newShot: Int(distanceYards), shotClub: shotClub)
                //print(shotClub.strokesList)
                shotClub = club
                if shotClub.putter == true {
                    waiting = false
                }
            }, label: {
                Text("Start Putting")
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.system(.title, design: .rounded, weight: .bold))
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            })
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        entity: Club.entity(),
        sortDescriptors:[
                          NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Club.yardsNum, ascending: false)],
        animation: .default)
    private var clubs:FetchedResults<Club>
    //@State private var waiting = false
    //@State private var shotCoord = CLLocation(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
    //@State private var ballCoord = CLLocation(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
    @State private var shotClub = Club()
    @State private var showNewClub: Bool = false
    @StateObject private var locationManager = LocationManagerModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            ZStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(clubs) {club in 
                        NavigationLink(destination: ClubDetailView(club: club, waiting: $locationManager.waiting,shotCoord: $locationManager.shotCoord, ballCoord: $locationManager.ballCoord,  shotClub: $shotClub), label:{HStack {
                            Text(club.name)
                            Spacer()
                            if club.putter == false {
                                Text("\(club.yardsNum)y")
                            }
                        }} )
                    } //: ForEach
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteClub)
                } //: List
        
                
                if clubs.count == 0 && self.showNewClub == false{
                    Button("Tap to Start Adding Clubs!") {
                        self.showNewClub = true
                    } .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                        .font(.system(.largeTitle,design: .rounded))
                        
                }
                
                if self.showNewClub{
                    
                    BlankView()
                        .onTapGesture {self.showNewClub = false}
                        .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    NewClubView(isShow: self.$showNewClub)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                        .animation(.default, value: self.showNewClub)
                        .opacity(100)
                        .padding(.top)
                        
                        
                }
                
            } //: ZStack
            .navigationTitle("Clubs")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showNewClub = true
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                            .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                    } //: Button
                    
                } //: ToolbarItem
                
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                        .foregroundColor(.accentColor)
                        .opacity(100)
                        .disabled(self.clubs.count == 0)
                } //: ToolbarItem
//                if waiting == true{
//                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
//                        Button(action: {
//                            
//                            
//                        }, label: {
//                            Text("Start Putting")
//                        })
//                    }
//                }
            }
        }//: NavigationView
            //.searchable(text: self.$searchClub)
    }
    
    private func deleteClub(index: IndexSet) -> Void {
        withAnimation {
            index.map { clubs[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)
            
            do {
                try viewContext.save()
            } catch {
                let nsError = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError.localizedDescription), \(nsError.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried passing the variables directly from the `LocationManagerModel` to the `DetailView`, passing from `LocationManagerModel` to `ContentView` as `@State` then to `DetailView` as `@Binding`, and from `LocationManagerView` to `DetailView` as `@State` with varying success. What is confusing me the most is that `waiting` works as intended by passing it as an argument to the `DetailView` when called in the `ContentView` but the others do not.

Comment: Currently you declare two separate `@StateObject private var locationManager = LocationManagerModel()`, one in `ClubDetailView`, and one in `ContentView`, they have **no relations** to each other. 
You could use `@EnvironmentObject var locationManager: LocationManagerModel`  in `ClubDetailView` and 
pass the model to it from `ContentView` using `.environmentObject(locationManager)`.
Have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app:  [monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

Comment: @workingdog support Ukraine That was it! Thanks for your help! If you submit this as an answer I'll be sure to mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you declare two separate `@StateObject private var locationManager = LocationManagerModel()`, one in `ClubDetailView`, and one in `ContentView`, they have no relations to each other.

You need to have only **one** source of truth.
So you could use `@EnvironmentObject var locationManager: LocationManagerModel` in `ClubDetailView` and pass the model to it from `ContentView` using `.environmentObject(locationManager)`.